# Using mouseClicked and mouseDragged indipendantly

Tags: java, jython, mouselistener

I am trying to write a Jython script in Fiji (ImageJ) that allows a user to place a point and upon placing the point adds it to the region of interest manager. This I can do but I also wish the user to be able to drag and drop already placed points without adding a new entry in the region of interest manager. Basically I want to be able to call mouseClicked and mouseDragged independently from each other whereas currently dragging the mouse will still activate a mouseClicked event. (I didn't know whether to put down Java as one of the tags but I feel it's closely related enough, I apologize if wrong).

Cheers!

```
class ML(MouseAdapter):
 def mouseClicked(self, event):
   canvas = event.getSource()
   imp = canvas.getImage()
   print click
   roi.runCommand("Add") 
   roi.runCommand("UseNames", "true")

class ML2(MouseAdapter):
 def mouseDragged(self, event):
   canvas = event.getSource()
   imp = canvas.getImage()
   print "move!"

roi = ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager()
listener = ML()
listener2 = ML2()

for imp in map(WindowManager.getImage, WindowManager.getIDList()):
 win = imp.getWindow()
 if win is None:
   continue
 win.getCanvas().addMouseListener(listener)
 win.getCanvas().addMouseMotionListener(listener2)
```

Comment: so you want on click to add a point and drag to drag a point, or can click on an existing point will cause to lift it?

Comment: yeah, click to add and drag to drag. The problem is that dragging still causes a click event to happen and so you get both actions (adding and dragging) occuring

Comment: i had an exercise with such requirements but that was java, not jython; if i remember correctly i used a boolean to block mouseClick. let me check..

Comment: ok, i left mouseClicked empty and used mousePressed instead with said boolean. if you want ill upload the code and give you a link to it

Comment: If you don't mind that would be great! I think it would be quite handy to be able to see it.

Comment: for the immediate relevant code search for //HERE http://pastebin.com/XnwMPQqZ good luck!

Comment: so how helpful was it?

Comment: I think I got it thanks! The example was very useful.

Comment: care to accept an answer by me then?

Comment: How do you do that if it has been answered in the comments? there appears to be no tick next to these things!

Comment: right, ill simply post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

/**
 * handles mouse pressed event
 */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
{
    // if filling we shouldn't add anything 
    if(b_Filling == true)
        return;
    // if dragging we shouldn't add anything
    if(isDragging == true)
        return;

    // handles first vertex for each polygon
    if(i_ThreeVertices == 0)
    {
        p_Start = arg0.getPoint();
        p_End = new Point();
        p_FirstVertex = new Point(p_Start);
    }
    else
    {
        // not the first vertex
        p_Start = new Point(p_End);
        p_End = arg0.getPoint();
    }

    // adds the vertex
    b_Drawing = true;
    addAPoint();
    b_Drawing = false;
    b_repaintFlag = true;
    // repaints
    this.repaint();
}

/**
 * handles mouse released event
 */
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
{
    // if filling we shouldn't add a vertex.
    if(b_Filling == true)
        return;

    if(b_FirstVertexInPolygon == true && isDragging == false)
    {
        // unlocks first vertex state
        b_FirstVertexInPolygon = false;
        return;
    }

    // save previous vertex and add current if mouse is dragged 
    // and more than non vertices
    if(isDragging == true && i_ThreeVertices != 0)
    {
        p_Start = new Point(p_End);
        p_End = arg0.getPoint();

        isDragging = false;
        b_Drawing = true;
        // adds a vertex
        addAPoint();
        b_Drawing = false;
    }
    else
        p_End = arg0.getPoint();
    b_repaintFlag = true;
    // repaint
    this.repaint();
}

/**
 * handles mouse dragged event
 */
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0)
{
    // repaints if not filling
    if(b_Filling == true)
        return;
    p_End = arg0.getPoint();
    isDragging = true;
    b_repaintFlag = true;
    this.repaint();
}

/**
 * handles mouse moved event
 */
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
{
    // if not filling, and we have at least one vertex
    // and not dragging mouse, then repaint.
    if(b_Filling == true)
        return;
    if(i_ThreeVertices == 0)
        return;
    if(isDragging == true)
        return;
    p_End = arg0.getPoint();
    b_repaintFlag = true;
    this.repaint();
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0){
}
```

Comment: thw whole code is here (this time i made sure it wont expire) 
http://pastebin.com/r41bJZcD